# Seeking in-depth understanding of Function<T,R>

Tags: java, functional-interface, functional-java

Shown below is some sample code that uses Java Streams.  My question specifically pertains to `Interface Function<T,R>` which accepts an input of type `T` and returns something of type `R`.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Dish {

  private final String name;
  private final boolean vegetarian;
  private final String calories;

  public Dish(String name, boolean vegetarian, String calories) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
    this.calories = calories;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public boolean isVegetarian() {
    return vegetarian;
  }

  public String getCalories() {
    return calories;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  public static final List<Dish> menu = asList(
      new Dish("pork", false, "GE 600"),
      new Dish("beef", false, "GE 600"),
      new Dish("chicken", false, "300-600"),
      new Dish("french fries", true, "300-600"),
      new Dish("rice", true, "LE 300"),
      new Dish("season fruit", true, "LE 300"),
      new Dish("pizza", true, "300-600"),
      new Dish("prawns", false, "300-600"),
      new Dish("salmon", false, "300-600")
  );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Dish>> dishByCalories = menu.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Dish::getCalories));
        System.out.println(dishByCalories);
  }
}
```

Obviously `groupingBy(Dish::getCalories)` is meeting the expected method signature requirements of `collect` (i.e. `Collector<? super T,A,R> collector`)

Now coming to `groupingsBy`, its signature requirements are the following:
`static <T,K> Collector<T,?,Map<K,List<T>>> groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier)`

The method reference that we are passing to `groupingsBy` is `Dish::getCalories`

Obviously `Dish::getCalories` is meeting the signature requirements of `Function<? super T,? extends K>` (i.e. it should accept an input of some superclass of T and return a result of some subclass of K).

However, the `getCalories` method **does not accept any arguments** and it returns a String.

Kindly help clear my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCalories` is an *instance* method, so it accepts the implicit `this` argument.

`Dish::getCalories` is equivalent to lambda `(Dish dish) -> dish.getCalories()`, which makes it an implementation of `Function<Dish, String>`.